# database login window pop ups whenever i run my report with a subreport using crystal report in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

This line of codes runs fine without the subreport.

```
    Dim rpt As New CRaipPrepare

    rpt.DataSourceConnections.Clear()
    rpt.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection(connection.server, db.aipDB, connection.user, connection.pass)
    rpt.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).IntegratedSecurity = False

    'rpt.Subreports.Item("CRsignatory.rpt").SetDataSource(subrpt)

    rpt.SetParameterValue("@id", Dashboard.BurgerMenuItem.Tag)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("@sector", code)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("@year", Yeardate)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("@stats", IIf(Prepare.checkfinale(Dashboard.BurgerMenuItem.Tag) = 3, 2, Nothing))

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(zooming)
```

Now with the subreport, whenever i run my report the database login windows always pop ups. Even the integrated security in the subreport is set to false

```
    Dim rpt As New CRaipPrepare
    Dim subrpt As New CRsignatory

    subrpt.DataSourceConnections.Clear()
    subrpt.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection(connection.server, db.aipDB, connection.user, connection.pass)
    subrpt.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).IntegratedSecurity = False

    subrpt.SetParameterValue("@idBrgy", Dashboard.BurgerMenuItem.Tag)
    subrpt.SetParameterValue("@dateYear", Yeardate)


    rpt.DataSourceConnections.Clear()
    rpt.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection(connection.server, db.aipDB, connection.user, connection.pass)
    rpt.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).IntegratedSecurity = False

    'rpt.Subreports.Item("CRsignatory.rpt").SetDataSource(subrpt)

    rpt.SetParameterValue("@id", Dashboard.BurgerMenuItem.Tag)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("@sector", code)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("@year", Yeardate)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("@stats", IIf(Prepare.checkfinale(Dashboard.BurgerMenuItem.Tag) = 3, 2, Nothing))

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(zooming)
```

I've been struggling to fine solution in this problem. Glad for any help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

SetConnection may not work if you are overwriting the server. It is applicable when setting paswords